# Equirectangular sky texture in Blender Internal?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, world

Is it possible to use an equirectangular sky texture as a world background in Blender Internal?

I'm used to doing this in Cycles, but don't know if there's a BI equivalent:

[image: Equirectangular environment map in Cycles]

I would like to avoid mapping the environment texture onto a UV sphere if there is a more elegant way. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

---

To make equirectangular texture enhance your scene in Blender Internal, create a texture for World Background and add your map in there.

1. Open **World** scroll, check *Real Sky*. Without this setting texture still will work but the view won't change if rotating camera. Then go to **Textures** tab to create a new texture for the world.
2. In the new texture properties leave it on *Image or Movie*, open equirectangular map.
3. In the *Mapping* scroll change coordinates to *Equirectangular*.
4. In the *Influence* tab uncheck *Blend* and choose *Horizon*. It's rather handy to look at *Preview World* scroll while changing these, as it will change according to steps done.

   [image]

   Note that as mentioned by @Mentalist in order to see your equirectangular map in the render you should also set *Alpha Mode* to *Sky* instead of *Transparent* in **Render** > **OpenGL Render Options** (if it was changed before).

   [image]
5. If you'd like to make the map affect the scene lighting, enable *Environment Lighting* and set it to *Sky Texture*.

   [image]

Also according to [the post on BA](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?267083-2-63-13-Equirectangular-Skies), supporting of equirectangular maps in BI has been added rather long ago.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I noticed that when I load a .hdr image, while I can boost the Energy to shine more light on the objects in the scene, the sky image itself does not brighten. Do you happen to know if there is a setting to make an HDRi sky appear brighter? Also, I encountered one issue worth mentioning - my background was rendering as transparent at first, even after following all your steps. It was because in my startup .blend I have OpenGL renders set to use transparent backgrounds. This was fixed by going to the menu and choosing **Render > OpenGL Render Options > Alpha Mode: Sky**

Comment: @Mentalist I can't think of any useful ways to brighten hdri map only if not using some hacks like setting *Horizon* to 2 in texture properties (note that it seems to increase saturation, not brightness) or playing with colors in **World** tab. As to issue - I'll edit the answer and I'm surprised btw to see that it affects *final* render, not only OpenGL which I often use for previewing animations.